# Camel resequencer removing the initial time

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camels resequencer in the 'stream' mode to insure that files are processed in the correct order

```
.resequence(new MySequencingExpression()).stream().timeout(60000))
```

The timeout has to be in the order of minutes as we have the occasionally get files that are completely out of order

When I run this up I have noticed that the processing on the first file will be delayed the timeout period - which is totally unacceptable for us.

Having examined the code the initial delay occurs because the code is essentially trying to compare the first file to its non existent  predecessor and then timing out.  What it should be doing is something like *'have I had a file in the last timeout period, then if so, was it the correct predecessor?'*

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks

Richard

Comment: I think this is functioning as intended. You probably need to review whether you need to use a resequencer or something else.

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/resequencer.html states: "a message with the sequence number 3 has a predecessor message with the sequence number 2 and a successor message with the sequence number 4. The message sequence 2,3,5 has a gap because the successor of 3 is missing. The resequencer therefore has to retain message 5 until message 4 arrives (or a timeout occurs)." Isn't this therefore what you expect? ie it holds onto the first message until the timeout or second message arrives in case the second message is earlier in the sequence.

Comment: Give the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4 and given that 1 and 2 have arrived - at this point the code could start processing . Currently the code waits for the timeout period which IMHO looks like a bug...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, please refer to the ResequencerEngine [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/resequencer/ResequencerEngine.html)

> If the last-delivered element is null i.e. the resequencer was newly
>   created the first arriving element needs timeout milliseconds in any
>   case for becoming ready-for-delivery.

Regarding your comment:

> Give the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4 and given that 1 and 2 have arrived - at
>   this point the code could start processing

What about if after 1 and 2 came 0?

I think it would be great if the developers allowed user to set the first expected value, because usually we know what it is and it would save unnecessary delay at resequencer startup, but I don't think its currently possible.